# Having upvote on an answer trade off a downvote on the question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes, post-ban

I wonder if a Stack Overflow user can escape from the warning *danger of being blocked from asking any more* by posting a well-received answer instead of posting well received question of fixing old questions. Is it possible **and fine**?

Comment: Isn't this something we encourage, though?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Being able to answer questions well is no indicator of your ability to ask questions well. I've seen more than a few high-rep users with hundreds of answers, that ask pretty terrible questions. (This can happen when the majority of questions they answer are themselves terrible, but how well exactly can you consistently answer bad questions?)

If answer upvotes have any effect on a question block at all is deliberately left ambiguous, but don't expect it to have a *meaningful* effect. If you don't want to get blocked from asking questions, improve your existing questions and get better at asking future questions. No two ways about it.

Comment: It's been said that answer votes do affect a question ban (and vice versa), it just has a much smaller effect than votes on questions (or answers, when considering answer bans).  The *degree* of the difference in weighting has never been specified.